# Replace for loop with apply function

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

My question is how to use "apply" function to do what "for loop" does in this example:

```
mtcars

for (i in colnames(mtcars)){
    print(head(mtcars[i]))
}
```

What I need is to get R to read one column after the other, ideally by index (ie mtcars[1], then mtcars[2], then mtcars[3]...) rather than colnames.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @eipi your code isn't producing any output with row names like OP's for-loop.

Comment: No, plafort, the output of the for-loop is giving me exactly what I need (the columns one after the other), but I'd like to have it written with apply rather...

Comment: There is no way to get `apply` to do that for you. It coerces its first argument to a matrix and removes the column names. Consider using `lapply` ... and do explain what you will be doing more expansively.

Comment: Thank you BondedDust, I'm trying actually with lapply, let's see...

Answer (score 1):

Use the apply function

```
apply(mtcars, 2 ,head)
```

this is the result

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

**Explanation**

`2` in the parameter of apply function means you're going to pass each column to your defined function , if you pass `1` instead of `2` this means that you're going to send each row instead of column

Comment: Instead of writing out so much, `apply(mtcars, 2, head)`

Comment: Thank you guys, what I need is to get the columns one then the other  as in my example with for-loop (also, in the example I used head just to print few lines but I need the whole column).

Comment: @yankee Why does it matter how it's printed on the screen? The information is the same. What are you doing next with the data?

Comment: It's a dataset where I have a set of genes in every column and I need to feed a function with these columns one after the other.